# Javascript | SVG object jumps after rotation

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an SVG object (a rectangle, which is also draggable using x and y attributes) via rotate(angle x y), x and y is the midpoint of the object which I calculate with this function:

```
getMidPoint(x, y, width, height, angle, oldMidPointX, oldMidPointY, drawPoint) {
    let angleRad = angle * Math.PI / 180;
    let cosa = Math.cos(angleRad);
    let sina = Math.sin(angleRad);

    // Find new x/y values after rotation
    let tempX = x - oldMidPointX;
    let tempY = y - oldMidPointY;

    let xAfterRotation = (tempX * cosa) - (tempY * sina);
    let yAfterRotation = (tempX * sina) + (tempY * cosa);

    drawPoint(x, y, "aqua");

    // translate back
    x = xAfterRotation + oldMidPointX;
    y = yAfterRotation + oldMidPointY;

    drawPoint(x, y, "green");

    let wp = width / 2;
    let hp = height / 2;

    let px = x + (wp * cosa) - (hp * sina);
    let py = y + (wp * sina) + (hp * cosa);

    drawPoint(x, y, "red");

    return {
        px: px,
        py: py };
}
```

Consecutive rotations are no problem. The jumping occurs if the object gets rotated, resized (for example increasing the width of the object) and then rotated again. While the function above gives the correct midpoint, the object first jumps and rotates around the the calculated point.

I don't know what I'm missing here, maybe someone can spot the mistake or give me some ideas to try out.

**EDIT**
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAJws.png) is an image to showcase my problem.
1: Starting position; red dot marks the midpoint of the object and green dot is the position used for calculating the midpoint.
2: Rotating the object with no problem.
3: Resizing the object.
4: Calculating new midpoint on start; blue dot marks x and y coordinates of the object.
5: Rotating the second time, "jumping" occurs.
6-8: The object rotates (the same rotation started at previous step) around the midpoint but with an offset.
9: 360° rotation puts the top left corner of the object to it's x/y position
Maybe someone can spot the mistake now.

Comment: What do you mean by "jumping"?

Comment: The object moves a certain distance away from the original position.